# Perforce P4W error: file(s) not in client view

Tags: view, client, perforce, depot

I have an existing workspace that I have been using and everything has been working as expected.

Now I am beginning a new project and would like to change my workspace root so that the files will be located in a different directory, for example, `C:/NewProject`.

I have made the `/NewProject` folder and added files to it, which I can see in my workspace view.

When I try to `Mark for Add...` I get a warning `c:\NewProject\FileName - file(s) not in client view`

How can I add these files to my depot?  Or to the client view so that I may successfully add them?

Answer (score 34):

You can edit your client view through *Connection -> Edit Current Workspace* in the View tab (or something similar; I'm on a p4 client from 2011).  If you're working in a relatively small depot, you might as well just include `//depot/...` in your view.

Comment: Are your files located under c:\ztest\ztestdepot in the file system?

Answer (score 27):

Usually after installing Perforce to a new computer, when you try to sync Depot files the system gives sync error message "File(s) not in client view". Here is the solution:

1. Go to **Connection** > **Edit Current Workspace** > Expand the **Workspace Mappings** field to display the Depot Tree.
2. Right-click on the name of the Depot Tree that you want to "Include" in mappings.
3. Click **Apply**, click **Get Latest** to sync the files.

Comment: Remember to hit "Add Files" too if you have files in that folder itself that you want to submit

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with it for hours, I finally sort it out.
It's very simple, just **Add your folder name** to the mapping.
My situation is the folder name is not the same as the workspace name "deport".

(Auto-generated for you in the Workspace Mappings)

```
//depot/... //alice_1545/depot/...
```

So all you need to do is **add** your folder name into the Workspace Mappings.

```
//depot/... //alice_1545/depot/...
//depot/... //alice_1545/{your folder name}/...
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe Tuan's answer works. In my case, I had to change the default configuration for client:

In command line, type

```
p4 client your_workspace_name_here
```

Edit the lines below **View:**

Change

```
//mydepot/... //your_workspace_name_here/mydepot...
```

To

```
//mydepot/... //your_workspace_name_here/...
```

Answer (score 1):

//dev/project-app/...#head - file not in client view.

Problem:

while trying to get some file it fails and throws error

//dev/project-app/...#head - file not in client view.
p4 sync //dev/project-app/...#head
    no files updated
    1 warning reported

Solution:

Perforce depot or path not in view. Edit your workspace to include the required path.

For example in above case - GO   Connection -> Edit current workspace -> click tab on 'View' -> choose the required depot and include tree(dev)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you are not using(commit or update) the workspace for a long time.
Go to **View -> Unloaded -> Workspace** path in Perforce. Select and Right click on the Workspace which you want to load it again and select "load". Then logoff and login perforce again will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the exactly same problem when setting up a blank project: You will need to create a folder named exactly as the Workspace name in order for the path to be recognized by Perforce. For example this works: Workspace name: MY_PROJECT_123, Workspace root: E:\Perforce\MY_PROJECT_123, but this doesn't work: Workspace name: MY_PROJECT_123, Workspace root: E:\Perforce\SOME_PROJECT. [workspace naming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmn1e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Type 'p4 client' on terminal which opens a editor with all mappings in your client. if you see the path of that **directory** that complains, just adding (...) like below will help

**directory**/... **directory**/...