# Unity and P4V Error - file(s) not in client view?

Tags: unity-game-engine, perforce, p4v

I've looked through several other SO posts pertaining to this and have tried the solutions mapped out here [Perforce P4W error: file(s) not in client view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356666/perforce-p4w-error-files-not-in-client-view) . I am trying to use P4V with my Unity project and am getting the error `file(s) not in client view` when I try to add project folders like "Assets" or "ProjectSettings."

My Unity project is located in my root p4v folder in the workspace folder. When I right click my depot > Map to Workspace View, I see my workspace name correctly entered, my workspace root set to my workspace folder, and a list of workspace mappings.

I have tried adding the following to my list of mappings: `//depot/... //{workspace}/{unity folder name}/...` however this does nothing / does not save even when I hit Apply. I see no errors on the Unity side, just that everything is marked "Local."

I have never set up a Perforce project with Unity before - how can I add my files to P4V?

EDIT:

Local path Im trying to add: `/Users/{username}/Perforce/{workspace-name}/{unity-project-folder}`

Workspace Root: `/Users/{username}/Perforce/{workspace-name}`

I do not know where to find View path.

Comment: You're getting that error because the local folders you're trying to add need to map to the depot via the client workspace's `View` and `Root`, and they don't.  The fix is probably very simple, but it's impossible to give you any useful guidance on it without knowing exactly what the `View` and `Root` are and the exact local path of the folders you're trying to add.

Comment: Check out _[Client Workspace Views](https://p1community.force.com/Community2/s/article/2490)_, Perforce Community Portal.

Comment: @Samwise ok - I have updated question with Root and local folder paths. I do not know where to find View path / what that describes

Comment: The `View` is the thing that looks like `//depot/blahblah/... //{workspace-name}/blahblah/...`.   You might need to go to some kind of "advanced mode" in P4V to be able to see it plainly -- or just go to the CLI and run `p4 client -o` to make it easy! Seeing your current View would provide hints as to where in the depot you might want this folder to go -- if you could also explicitly indicate what depot path you want the added folder to go into that would be good too.